# Wordpress — получить размер картинки?

Tags: wordpress, изображения

Такой вопрос, Google PageSpeed ругается на то, что для картинок не заданы соотв. размеры, подскажите, а как в шаблоне можно вывести размер картинки, если на каждой странице он разный. Т.е. необходимо как-то получить размер картинки, чтобы в дальнейшем вывести его в теге img.

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйтесь функциями WordPress для вывода картинок, например, https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_attachment_image. Они правильно работают с srcset.